# Swift Rest Api call trouble

Tags: swift, rest

bellow shows me trying to call an API after two text boxes have been filled out (height and weight) and I button is pressed. I am not getting any errors however the labels are not being updated with the correct values. Thank you in advance!

View Controller

```
         func fetchData() {
            let h = Double(height.text!)
            let w = Double(weight.text!)
            let urlString = "http://webstrar99.fulton.asu.edu/page3/Service1.svc/calculateBMI?height=\(h!)&weight=\(w!)"
             guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
             URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                 do {
                     let jsonMessage = try JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: data!)
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.resultsBMI.text = String(jsonMessage.bmi)
                        self.resultsMessage.text = jsonMessage.risk
                     }
                 } catch {}
             }.resume()
         }
    }
```

API Model

```
struct Message: Codable {
    let bmi: Double
    let risk: String

    enum MessageKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case bmi, risk
       }
```

Comment: Isn't that because you are setting text values to labels before URLSession completes its task?

Comment: Wait.  What does the catch say?  Change `catch {}` to catch let error as NSError {
 print("\(error)")
}

Comment: @ElTomato I changed the catch but I am still getting the same thing where "nothing" happens.

Comment: Print jsonMessage after let jsonMessage = ... to see if you have a result.